# Computation of volume under isosurface in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, volume, computation

I have a problem with MATLAB and I cannot figure out a solution. I have some volume data wrapped into an isosurface. Say that it's similar to this:

[image: MRI Image].

How can I compute the volume inside the isosurface?

Comment: (More details please...) How is the isosurface represented in MATLAB?

Comment: isosurface(x,y,z,V,100)
which is passed as parameter to a patch

Comment: Would a `nnz(V>=100)` followed by unit cell volume normalization (conversion) be sufficient?